# Git - clone another project branch to current project

Tags: git, clone

I have two remote projects; proj1 and proj2

I have created a local repository of proj2

```
git init
git remote add proj2 <url>
git fetch --all --prune
```

This gives me two branches - master and develop. I change to develop

```
git checkout develop
```

with the template we use I now have a number of empty project directories. However I want to remove these and copy over the contents from the develop branch of proj1.

I've tried using clone but to no effect.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple remotes and fetch from them:

```
git remote add proj2 <url>
git remote add proj1 <url>
git fetch --all
```

You now have both `proj1` and `proj2` in your local repo, including references to the remote branches (`proj1/develop`, `proj1/master`, `proj2/develop`, `proj2/master`, etc..)  You can merge, cherry-pick, or any other git operation between these branches to do what you need. You can selectively push your changes to `proj1` or `proj2` or both.

```
git checkout develop
git merge proj1/develop
git merge proj2/develop
<make more changes and resolve conflicts>
git commit -a
git push proj2 develop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just fork the repository into another project. For more information. https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/27/using-fork-branch-git-workflow/